# Validation shows Incorrect value in Table - Cakephp

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp, input

I have an edit form that pops up in a jQuery dialog box and it has an Ajax submit button to perform validation without closing the dialog box or redirecting it to some other page.  My problem is that in my form I show the current value as well as an empty input box for the new value and if the new value is not a number the current value still changes to that value.

For example if the edit window shows an "in month" current value of 5 and the user enters 5sdf the validation will kick in and say fix the errors but the current value column will now show 5sdf.  I need help keeping the current value to stay its most recent valid value.

Here is my code for the edit action in the controller:

```
public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $this->LocalClock->id = $id;
        $this->set('isEditValid', false);
        $this->set('editValidationErrors', false);

        if ($this->request->is('get'))
        {
               $this->request->data = $this->LocalClock->read();
               $this->set('localClocks', $this->LocalClock->read());
            }
            else
            {
               if ($this->LocalClock->save($this->request->data))
               {
                $this->set('isEditValid', true);
                $this->set('editValidationErrors', false);
                $this->set('localClocks', $this->request->data);
            }
               else
               {
                $this->set('isEditValid', false);
                $this->set('editValidationErrors', true);
                $this->set('localClocks', $this->request->data);
               }
        }
    }
```

Here is my edit.ctp:

```
<div id="edit_table">

<div id="edit_errors">
</div>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('LocalClock', array('action' => 'edit', 'inputDefaults' => array('label' => false))); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Field</th>  <th>Current Value</th>  <th>New Value</th>
    </tr></thead>

    <tbody>
<tr><td>Name</td><td> <?php echo $localClocks['LocalClock']['name']; ?></td><td>  <?php echo $this->Form->input('LocalClock.name', array('id' => 'focusMeEdit'));?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Auto Offset</td><td><?php echo $localClocks['LocalClock']['auto_offset'];?> </td><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('LocalClock.auto_offset');?> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>UTC Offset Sec</td><td><?php echo $localClocks['LocalClock']['utc_offset_sec'];?> </td><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('LocalClock.utc_offset_sec');?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>In Month</td><td><?php echo $localClocks['LocalClock']['in_month'];?></td>  <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('LocalClock.in_month');?> </td>  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php
    // The Ajax Helper submit is used to submit the changes made to the edit form
    // because it allows the modal window to be loaded with the updated edit view
    // without leaving the modal window. 
    echo $this->Ajax->submit('Save Changes', array(
        'url' => array('controller' => 'localClocks', 'action' => 'edit'),
        'update' => 'edit_table'));

    // Call the close Dialog() function if data was validated sucessfully; valid == true. 
    // Else it stays open displaying validation error message.
    if (false != $isEditValid)
    {
        echo "<script>$('#[id*=dialog]').dialog('close');</script>";
        echo "<script>$('#success_messages').dialog('open');</script>";
        echo "<script>$('#success_messages').text('Local Clock Successfully Edited')</script>";
    }
    if(false != $editValidationErrors)
    {
        echo "<script>$('#edit_errors').html('<h3><em><font color=\"red\">Please Correct Errors Before Proceeding</font></em></h3>')</script>";
    }

echo $this->Form->end(); ?>

</div>
```

I am not sure if the problem is in my action or view that is causing it to happen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the standard behaviour to show the incorrect value. If you had typed a long answer which for some reason was invalid you wouldn't want the answer removed otherwise you may have a lot of retyping to do.

After the save has failed why not read in the original record, check $this->LocalClock->invalidFields() for the errors and replace $this->request->data with the original values of affected fields?

Comment: How do I access the original records?  Is there a variable I can call or is it in the $this->request->data.  I am new to this stuff so bear with me.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Retrieve them  

$orig_local_clock = $this->LocalClock->findById($this->request->data['LocalClock']['id']);

Dont use $model->read or you will clear the validation messages.

Comment: Good news everyone! - That worked. For anyone else who has the same problem, I placed the line from Leo's comment above as the first statement in the edit function.  Then in the bottom else statement statement, change the last line to `$this->set('localClocks', $orig_local_clock);`. - Thanks Leo

Comment: Just a heads up, the way my edit action is setup, it requires an if statement:
`if(null == $id) $orig_local_clock = $this->LocalClock->findById($this->request->data['LocalClock']['id']); else $orig_local_clock = $this->LocalClock->findById($id)`
This will take care of a small bug that pops up saying the index variable is unknown.